# Correct punctation when two quotations are used in the same sentence (British usage)

Tags: punctuation, british-english, quotation-marks

Is the following sentence correctly punctuated for British English usage:

I said, 'It's important to learn grammar', and he said, 'I promise I will'.

Comment: No. Use double quotation marks, and put the comma and period inside the quotation marks. I said, "It's important to learn grammar," and he said, "I promise I will."

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that American English usage?

Comment: What style guide are you using?

Comment: I've looked at the University of Oxford Style Guide and in the Penguin Guide to Pronunciation but I can't find the answer.

Ideally, I would like to know if the second quotation starts with a capital letter too.

Comment: Even in British punctuation, when you're quoting a *complete* sentence, the punctuation at the end of the sentence being quoted goes *before* the final quotation mark. (It's a misunderstanding that it doesn't.) In your sentence, you are quoting two *complete* sentences, so both the comma and period actually go inside the closing quotation marks: *I said, 'It's important to learn grammar,' and he said, 'I promise I will.'* The *University of Oxford Style Guide* gives an example of that, but it's not entirely clear. However, I've written to the editor in the past, so I know this to be true.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer @JasonBassford   

Could you also confirm if a capital letter should begin the second quotation, please? In the example above, the second quotation begins with the word 'I', but what if it is 'the'?

Comment: @PhilHatcher When you introduce a quotation of a sentence, the first letter of the quoted sentence is capitalized. (Unless you employ something like a dash or  ellipsis, but that's something specifically different.) So, yes.